# Issue with querying data with NativeSearchQuery from Elasticsearch

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm new to Spring Elasticsearch and trying to build native query, however, I get following error message ;

> 2023-01-23T21:54:56.127+03:00 ERROR 46803 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unhandled Query implementation

> org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.erhlc.NativeSearchQuery] with root cause

I created two "BoolQueryBuilder" objects like below, My goal is to retrieve records with value "winlog.event_data.Status" equal to 0x18 or 0xC000006A and value of "winlog.event_data.TargetUserName" is USER001.

```
        BoolQueryBuilder errorQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("winlog.event_data.Status","0x18"))
                .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("winlog.event_data.Status","0xC000006A"));

        BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("winlog.event_data.TargetUserName","USER001"))
                .must(errorQuery);
```

Finally, when I run the queries as follows, I get the error I mentioned at the beginning of the topic.

```
        NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(boolQueryBuilder).build();

        System.out.println(searchQuery.getQuery());

        List<SearchHit<Winlog>> articles = elasticsearchOperations
                .search(searchQuery, Winlog.class, IndexCoordinates.of("winlog"))
                .getSearchHits();
```

but if I print the query with the following output and use this query directly in the ElasticsearchRepository interface, it works without any problems.

```
System.out.println(searchQuery.getQuery());
```

so i couldn't understand the problem.

```
@Repository
public interface WinlogRepository  extends ElasticsearchRepository<Winlog,String> {
    @Query("{\n" +
            "  \"bool\" : {\n" +
            "    \"must\" : [\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "        \"match\" : {\n" +
            "          \"winlog.event_data.TargetUserName\" : {\n" +
            "            \"query\" : \"?0\",\n" +
            "            \"operator\" : \"OR\",\n" +
            "            \"prefix_length\" : 0,\n" +
            "            \"max_expansions\" : 50,\n" +
            "            \"fuzzy_transpositions\" : true,\n" +
            "            \"lenient\" : false,\n" +
            "            \"zero_terms_query\" : \"NONE\",\n" +
            "            \"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query\" : true,\n" +
            "            \"boost\" : 1.0\n" +
            "          }\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "      },\n" +
            "      {\n" +
            "        \"bool\" : {\n" +
            "          \"should\" : [\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "              \"match\" : {\n" +
            "                \"winlog.event_data.Status\" : {\n" +
            "                  \"query\" : \"0x18\",\n" +
            "                  \"operator\" : \"OR\",\n" +
            "                  \"prefix_length\" : 0,\n" +
            "                  \"max_expansions\" : 50,\n" +
            "                  \"fuzzy_transpositions\" : true,\n" +
            "                  \"lenient\" : false,\n" +
            "                  \"zero_terms_query\" : \"NONE\",\n" +
            "                  \"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query\" : true,\n" +
            "                  \"boost\" : 1.0\n" +
            "                }\n" +
            "              }\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "              \"match\" : {\n" +
            "                \"winlog.event_data.Status\" : {\n" +
            "                  \"query\" : \"0xC000006A\",\n" +
            "                  \"operator\" : \"OR\",\n" +
            "                  \"prefix_length\" : 0,\n" +
            "                  \"max_expansions\" : 50,\n" +
            "                  \"fuzzy_transpositions\" : true,\n" +
            "                  \"lenient\" : false,\n" +
            "                  \"zero_terms_query\" : \"NONE\",\n" +
            "                  \"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query\" : true,\n" +
            "                  \"boost\" : 1.0\n" +
            "                }\n" +
            "              }\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "          ],\n" +
            "          \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n" +
            "          \"boost\" : 1.0\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "      }\n" +
            "    ],\n" +
            "    \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n" +
            "    \"boost\" : 1.0\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}\n")
        Page<Winlog> getAll(String name,Pageable pageable);

}
```

I couldn't understand why I'm getting error with "NativeSearchQuery".

stacktrace of error ;

```
2023-01-23T21:54:56.127+03:00 ERROR 46803 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unhandled Query implementation org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.erhlc.NativeSearchQuery] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unhandled Query implementation org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.erhlc.NativeSearchQuery
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.RequestConverter.getQuery(RequestConverter.java:1488) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.RequestConverter.searchRequest(RequestConverter.java:1059) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.RequestConverter.searchRequest(RequestConverter.java:1041) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchTemplate.search(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:322) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
    at com.test.lab.adldapels.controller.main.retrieve(main.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

pom.xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test.lab.adldapels</groupId>
    <artifactId>adldap-els</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>adldap-els</name>
    <description>adldap-els</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.17.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: please provide the complete stacktrace of the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unhandled Query implementation org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.erhlc.NativeSearchQuery
> at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.RequestConverter.getQuery(RequestConverter.java:1488) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]

You are using Spring Boot 3 and so Spring Data Elasticsearch 5 which uses the new Elasticsearch client. You have to use the `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.NativeQuery` class for this.

The `NativeSearchQuery` class was from the old implementation that was based on the old deprecated `RestHighLevelClient` from Elasticsearch.

See the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch-migration-guide-4.4-5.0.breaking-changes-packages):

> When working with the NativeSearchQuery class, you’ll need to switch to the NativeQuery class, which can take a Query instance coming from the new Elasticsearch client libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You are using spring-boot version 3.0 or later and And Java 17 version you use so in the `spring-data-elasticsearch` `NativeSearchQuery` and NativeQuery is deprecated and if you want to still use with spring boot 3.0 or later and java 17 then you can be use it just simply put the dependency as i share in below.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
  <version>7.17.5</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

And please maven need to be clean after that and install it still you faced an issue please let me know we solved that.